# cygwin sshd service crashes whenever I open certain file in /etc

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-sshd

When I try to vim /etc/profile or vim /etc/motd it stops.
When I try to `touch` those files it stops.

Any ideas?
Nothing in the ssh logs that seems to be pertinent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [similar message](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00666.html) on the Cygwin mailing list on July 31, 2012. The solution quoted there is:

> I've just applied a patch to fix this problem.  It seems this is a long
>   standing bug which could result in random stack corruption after changing
>   or adding any file to /etc.  I'm just generating a developer snapshot.
>   Please test the today's snapshot from http://cygwin.com/snapshots/
>   Just replacing /bin/cygwin1.dll with the snapshot DLL is sufficient.

So how about trying out this advice?

And seeing that you are quite active in SO, you may be interested in what seems to be [the actual fix to your problem](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/cygwin/path.cc.diff?r1=1.668&r2=1.669&cvsroot=src&f=h).